# Resultados de búsqueda en columnas Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Soy un chico que está realizando una página web propia sin tener mucha idea de programar ni de códigos y necesitaría ayuda.

Estoy atascado en la página de resultados de las búsquedas y no consigo editarla a mi gusto.

Me gustaría poder mostrar los resultados en 3 columnas (donde se incluiría la foto del post, el título, el resumen y el enlace).

Adjunto el código que tengo actualmente, que es que he conseguido hacer buscando en foros, pero se muestra todo en una única sección, y no puedo dividir en columnas los resultados.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages.
 *
 * @package stackstar.
 */

get_header(); ?>
    <div class="search-container">
    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
     
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
 
            <header class="page-header">
                <span class="search-page-title"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', stackstar ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></span>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->
 
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="entry">

    <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post Thumbnail
            the_post_thumbnail(medium);
        } else {
            //your default img
        }

        
?>

            <span class="search-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            <span class="search-post-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
            <span class="search-post-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_permalink(); ?></a></span>


    
            <?php endwhile; ?>
 
            <?php //the_posts_navigation(); ?>
 
        <?php else : ?>
 
            <?php //get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>
 
        <?php endif; ?>
 
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->
</div>
<?php //get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer();?>"
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con css, toma todo lo que este dentro de `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`y `<?php endwhile; ?>` y encapsula el contenido en un div, con css le puedes dar el formato de columna usando flexbox o inline-block, depende de como lo desees hacer, por ejemplo:

```
<div class="busqueda">
   <div class="columna">
     <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
       <?php /* Agrega tu contenido aqui */ ?>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Y en tus CSS algo asi

```
 <style>
    .busqueda {
       width: 90%;
       margin: auto;
       max-width: 1200px;
    }
    .columna {
       width: 32%;
       display: inline-block;
    }
 </style>
```

Si usas boostrap puedes usar el sistema de grillas de boostrap

Answer (score 0):

probé lo que me dijiste y sigo sin conseguir ponerlo en columnas.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying search results pages.
 *
 * @package stackstar.
 */

get_header(); ?>
   
     
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
 
            <header class="page-header">
                <span class="search-page-title"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Resultado de búsqueda para: %s', stackstar ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></span>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->
 
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<div class="busqueda">
 <div class="columna">
      
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                
            <span class="post_thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(medium); ?></span>
            <span class="search-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
            <span class="search-post-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>
           


    
            <?php endwhile; ?>
     
 </div>
</div>
            <?php //the_posts_navigation(); ?>
 
        <?php else : ?>
 
            <?php //get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>
 
        <?php endif; ?>
 
   
<?php //get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer();?>"
```

Adjunto imagen por si sirve de ayuda.
https://ibb.co/Kjz0wfJ

Muchas gracias!